# Error while executing the adaptiverandomforest with river libraray

Tags: random-forest, online-learning

I have installed rivery library and write the adaptiverandomforestregression program to apply onlinelearning and I am getting errror that AttributeError: module 'river.ensemble' has no attribute 'AdaptiveRandomForestRegressor'. i have installed all the basic libraries and getting atribute error. Could you please suggest me a solution.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What version of the `river` package are you using? If you check the documentation, you will see that [the `AdaptiveRandomForestRegressor` class was moved from `ensemble` to `forest` in v0.15](https://riverml.xyz/latest/releases/0.15.0/#forest). See [this page in the documentation](https://riverml.xyz/latest/api/forest/ARFRegressor/) for the new class.